# INSERT-statement with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to `INSERT` into a table, but I get the error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key contraint fails`.

And as the error says, I have a foreign key I'm trying to update.

Right now I'm using a simple `INSERT` like:

```
INSERT INTO tblTable1 (firstColumn, foreignKey) VALUES ('blabla', 1)
```

How can I insert this if `foreignKey` is the id of `tblTable2`?

Comment: Could you post the `create table statement` of tblTable1 and the result of `SELECT * FROM tblTable2 WHERE ID=1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the record to the parent table first, then the child table.

From MySQL documentation on [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB rejects any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create
>   a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table.

Here's MySQL documentation of [how to use foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html) and examples.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep your constaints. You cannot add record that does not have suitable value in related table!

Answer (score 2):

first insert that entry on which u applied foreign key constraint in Table2 then add run insert query in Table1. it will work